# Deploying .dll on remote sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create an assembly but my remote sql server cannot access my .dll file.

```
create assembly BarcodeSql 
from 'X:\test.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

I don't know how to put test.dll on my sql server, but I know I can send a serialized dll instead of the path to the dll.  How can I serialize the dll?  I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm trying to create an assembly but my remote sql server cannot access my .dll file.

That's because it is looking for `X:\` on the server where the SQL instance is running, not from where the SQL is being run from.

> How can I serialize the dll?

You can specify a network path in CREATE ASSEMBLY:

```sql
create assembly BarcodeSql 
from '\\yourmachine\sharetox\test.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

Or, you really could serialize it. Using PowerShell:

```
"0x" + [System.BitConverter]::ToString([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("X:\text.dll")).Replace("-", "")
```

Which will print out some large hex value. You can then use a VARBINARY literal when creating the assembly:

```sql
create assembly BarcodeSql 
from 0x23456789
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

Where 0x123456789 is the output of the powershell script.

Comment: How do I create a procedure from here?  My C# function takes arguments and returns a value.

Comment: @sooprise You would use `CREATE PROCEDURE .... AS EXTERNAL NAME  assembly_name.class_name.method_name`. See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It is just simple binary representation. You can use any HEX editor, or something like this:

```
public string GetAssemblyBits(string assemblyPath)
{
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      builder.Append("0x");

      using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(assemblyPath,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
      {
            int currentByte = stream.ReadByte();
            while (currentByte > -1)
            {
                  builder.Append(currentByte.ToString("X2",
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                  currentByte = stream.ReadByte();
            }
      }

      return builder.ToString();
}
```

Also, you can load assembly from network path.

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY assembly_name
[ AUTHORIZATION owner_name ]
FROM { <client_assembly_specifier> | <assembly_bits> [ ,...n ] }
[ WITH PERMISSION_SET = { SAFE | EXTERNAL_ACCESS | UNSAFE } ]
[ ; ]
<client_assembly_specifier> :: =
        '[\\computer_name\]share_name\[path\]manifest_file_name'
  | '[local_path\]manifest_file_name'

<assembly_bits> :: =
{ varbinary_literal | varbinary_expression }
```